# Problem with C++ Boost installation (can't find file) in VC++ 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, boost, linker

I freshly installed Boost 1.44 with the latest available installer from http://www.boostpro.com/download/. Then I created a VC++ unmanaged commandline project. I added the line `#include <boost/regex.hpp>` as stated in the Boost *Getting Started* tutorial, and I also put the Boost installation directory into the linking options. When I compile now, VS2010 reports a `fatal error LNK1104: file "libboost_regex-vc100-mt-gd-1_44.lib" cannot be opened`. I checked the installation directory and there's only the file `libboost_regex-vc100-mt-s-1_44.lib` (note `-gd-` vs `-s-`). Can anyone tell me what the problem is and how I can solve it? Thanks!

Comment: I remember having the same (or similar) problem. I looked at the directories and found another static library, copied and renamed it, everything worked after that. It seems to me the boost build process created the file with wrong name due to probably incorrectly defined macros.

Comment: I think the same. I solved it by doing a complete install, not just the "statically linked multithreaded" install, which should create `mt-s` but doesn't for some reason. And the `-gd-` one is automatically used by VS2010 when compiling in debug mode. In short: complete install fixes the problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Boost library naming convention is listed on the [Getting Started page](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/more/getting_started/windows.html#library-naming).

- `mt` indicates multithreading is enabled
- `g` indicates debug versions of the CRT libraries were linked
- `d` indicates the version of the boost libraries themselves that you're linking to are debug versions
- `s` indicates that the CRT libraries have been statically linked to by the boost libraries

What is probably happening is that you didn't get the BoostPro installer to download the missing flavors.

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studio 2010 provides the C++0x header `<regex>` for you.